# Problem with linear gradient react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, linear-gradients, expo

I am building  my first app in react native . When I try expo start i got this message .

Module../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/common.js

C:/Users/donikito/Desktop/app/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/common.js:6

I think it's problem with packages of Linear Gradient ,
I find three files sign in sign up splash screen , and make rootstack . And want to implement into  my projects.
this is command what i followed to install

npm install react-native-linear-gradient --save.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use this library with `expo`. The `react-native-linear-gradient` requires native modules ( BVLinearGradient ios).  You can use `expo-linear-gradient` as a replacement. 
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can i use also with expo

npm install react-native-animatable --save ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be the issue with the package or its version.

Remove the `node_modules` folder and install the package before trying npm install for adding the other packages.

```
npm install react-native-linear-gradient
npm install
```

For more: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient